# Find the largest nested-list of non-intersecting sets from an original nested-list

Tags: python, list, set, set-intersection

I have the following nested list (only integers).

```
L = [[9, 10, 14, 19, 11], [9, 11, 13, 12, 4], [40, 43, 44, 42, 41, 26, 14], [10, 16, 17, 26, 14], [25, 28, 20], [25, 20, 21, 27, 24], [3, 29, 22, 28], [25, 15, 2, 16, 17, 24], [0, 2, 16, 10, 9, 4], [0, 1, 29, 3], [29, 31, 32, 23, 22], [29, 31, 33, 8, 51, 1], [0, 1, 51, 50, 49, 39, 12, 4], [0, 2, 15, 3], [25, 15, 3, 28]]
```

I would like to find a nested list that groups the largest amount of non-intersecting sets coming from the original nested list (above). The output would be something like:

```
[[9, 11, 13, 12, 4], [40, 43, 44, 42, 41, 26, 14], [25, 20, 21, 27, 24], [3, 29, 22, 28], [0, 1, 51, 50, 49, 39, 12, 4]]
```

I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help ) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: for i in range(len(L)):
    if set(L[0]).isdisjoint(L[i]) == True:
        a = [c[0],c[i]]

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a graph problem. Each sublist is a node and there's an edge between them if they're disjoint. We want to [find the biggest cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), i.e. subgraphs where all pairs nodes are connected. This is an NP-complete problem so if `L` gets large this will take a while.

```
from networkx import Graph, find_cliques
from itertools import combinations, takewhile

L = [[9, 10, 14, 19, 11], [9, 11, 13, 12, 4], [40, 43, 44, 42, 41, 26, 14], [10, 16, 17, 26, 14], [25, 28, 20],
     [25, 20, 21, 27, 24], [3, 29, 22, 28], [25, 15, 2, 16, 17, 24], [0, 2, 16, 10, 9, 4], [0, 1, 29, 3],
     [29, 31, 32, 23, 22], [29, 31, 33, 8, 51, 1], [0, 1, 51, 50, 49, 39, 12, 4], [0, 2, 15, 3], [25, 15, 3, 28]]

L = map(tuple, L)

g = Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(L)

for sublist1, sublist2 in combinations(L, 2):
    if set(sublist1).isdisjoint(sublist2):
        g.add_edge(sublist1, sublist2)

cliques = sorted(find_cliques(g), key=len, reverse=True)
cliques = list(takewhile(lambda c: len(c) == len(cliques[0]), cliques))
for clique in cliques:
    flat = sum(clique, ())
    assert len(flat) == len(set(flat))
    print(sorted(flat))
    print(sorted(clique))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 51]
[(0, 2, 15, 3), (9, 11, 13, 12, 4), (10, 16, 17, 26, 14), (25, 28, 20), (29, 31, 33, 8, 51, 1)]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32]
[(0, 2, 15, 3), (9, 11, 13, 12, 4), (10, 16, 17, 26, 14), (25, 28, 20), (29, 31, 32, 23, 22)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 33, 51]
[(0, 2, 15, 3), (9, 11, 13, 12, 4), (10, 16, 17, 26, 14), (25, 20, 21, 27, 24), (29, 31, 33, 8, 51, 1)]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 32]
[(0, 2, 15, 3), (9, 11, 13, 12, 4), (10, 16, 17, 26, 14), (25, 20, 21, 27, 24), (29, 31, 32, 23, 22)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 51]
[(0, 2, 15, 3), (9, 11, 13, 12, 4), (25, 28, 20), (29, 31, 33, 8, 51, 1), (40, 43, 44, 42, 41, 26, 14)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 33, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 51]
[(0, 2, 15, 3), (9, 11, 13, 12, 4), (25, 20, 21, 27, 24), (29, 31, 33, 8, 51, 1), (40, 43, 44, 42, 41, 26, 14)]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
[(0, 2, 15, 3), (9, 11, 13, 12, 4), (25, 28, 20), (29, 31, 32, 23, 22), (40, 43, 44, 42, 41, 26, 14)]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 32, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
[(0, 2, 15, 3), (9, 11, 13, 12, 4), (25, 20, 21, 27, 24), (29, 31, 32, 23, 22), (40, 43, 44, 42, 41, 26, 14)]
```

The output is in pairs: first the flattened list, then the 2D list.

Comment: Alex, thanks a lot for your answer, it is really helpful. The issue came effectively from a graph problem.